# DataSet update in winform app 

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have some difficulty with the following: I have a dataset that I want to use to update the database when a change of value is made in the gridView. The dataset comes from the following method:

```
public static DataSet Display_all_members()
    {
        ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            string query = "SELECT date_to, last_name ,first_name , member_pay FROM  Member ";
            conS.Open();
          adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conS);
            adapter.Fill(ds, "To_display"); 
        }
        catch (Exception r)
        {}
        finally
        {
            conS.Close();
        }
        return ds;
    }
```

In the form I do

```
 ds2 = DAL.Display_all_members ();
 dataGridView1.DataSource = ds2;
 dataGridView1.DataMember = "To_display";
```

now I get to update and I do the following in the form

```
if (ds2.HasChanges() == true)
        {
            DAL.update(ds2);
        }
```

In the method

```
  public static void update(DataSet ki)
    {
           SqlCommandBuilder n = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
                da.Update(ds);

    }
```

And it doesn’t work. What’s the problem?
This is the error: **Update unable to find TableMapping['Table'] or DataTable 'Table'.**

Comment: 1) you don't really use the CommandBuilder, 2) You're not includeing a primary key, 3) you may need to pass that "To_display" to the update.

Comment: you can please update my qustion ,thank's

Comment: Can you post the actual SQL you are using to fill up the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

It might be just a typo, but your update method is using two different variables - `DataSet ki`, and `da` in the DataAdapter.Update() call.

Try this:

```
protected void update(DataSet ds)
{
    da.Update(ds, 'To_display")
}
```

From [DataAdapter DataTable and DataColumn Mappings (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks92fwwh%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

"If you do not specify a TableName or a DataTableMapping name when calling the Fill or Update method of the DataAdapter, the DataAdapter looks for a DataTableMapping named "Table". If that DataTableMapping does not exist, the TableName of the DataTable is "Table"."

If you're using the same DataSet that you originally filled, you'll probably want to keep specifying the table name where required to avoid this error.